# vim-workspace does not save set options

Tags: original-vim, sessions

I want to have a persisting vim setting in my workspace. The vim plugin vim-workspace seems to be the obvious solution for this. Yet it does not save some options.

For instance I want to have my spell checking enabled in one file and also set the spell dictionary. When I use `set spellfile=./en.utf-8.add` and `set spell spelllang=en`. The options are activated but when I `qa` and open vim again all buffers are loaded but the spell checking is disabled again.

I do not find anything in the help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim persists your workspace settings by writing/reading relevant workspace information into/from a [session-file](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#session-file). What kind of data gets written into that file is dictated by [`sessionoptions`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27sessionoptions%27), the contents of which you can inspect with `:set sessionoptions?`.

When you enabled the global spellcheck option with `:set spell` and then had your workspace information saved into the `session-file`, my guess is that Vim ignored including that global spellcheck option because `sessionoptions` was not configured to save global options yet. You should verify that by checking whether `options`(i.e. global options) is listed in the result of `:set sessionoptions?` and if it indeed is not listed, you can tell Vim to start tracking them by appending `options` onto `sessionoptions` with `:set sessionoptions+=options`. New sessions should contain all global options henceforth. You would probably want to place that command in your `vimrc`.

> .. I want to have my spell checking enabled in one file ...

If you intend to have an option that is only applicable locally e.g. `:setlocal spell`, you can start tracking `localoptions` in your sessions with: `set sessionoptions+=localoptions`.

About `vim-workspace` —  as far as I can tell from it's description, all it seems to do is manage your `session-file` for you, so you could probably rule it out as a potential source of interference.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the sessionoptions. I thought this was a feature that would come with vim-workspace. With your input I got my desired behavior. Important was to `set sessionoptions+=localoptions` after the import of the plugin in the vimrc.
One thing I do not get is that using `set sessionoptions+=options` does not change the output of `set seesionoptions?`. I put it in the end of the .vimrc and as far as I understand none of my other vim scripts gets loaded afterwards.